# Positioning SVG within a div

Tags: css, svg, inkscape

I'm trying to position an SVG within a div element. Should be simple: the div is position:relative, the SVG {position:absolute left:0 top:0}.

But the SVG doesn't appear at the top left corner, but somewhere in the middle of the div.

Trying to inspect the elements doesn't help: I can't seem to find the reason for the abnormal positioning.

But I have a suspicion: the SVG comes from Inkscape, with tons of metadata and obscure (to me) parameters such as "transform = matrix (...)". If I try to remove these transform lines the SVG either disappears or is otherwise bricked.

When I try the entire thing with an ultra-simple SVG (an inline rectangle, no Inkscape), no problem at all.

So what is it in the Inkscape markup that meddles with my SVG's positioning?

Thanks!

Comment: check the viewbox .. add border to your SVG to better understand

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read [ask] and update your question with a [mcve].  It is very hard to give advice without seeing your code.  It could be many things.

Comment: @TemaniAfif When I hover over the SVG in Inspect Element, I see nothing exceptional with the SVG's size. It occupies just a small box, without any hidden margins. This doesn't seem to explain this behaviour.